# Breadth First Search (BFS) Python Implementation...where is the bug here?

Tags: python, attributes, breadth-first-search

I have written the code below to implement breadth-first search using python. I'm not sure how the .children property is working and .val does not. I've added some print statements to see what's happening but I'm still not sure. The error I get when I run the code is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bfs.py", line 31, in 
    bfs(Node1)
  File "bfs.py", line 24, in bfs
    print popped.children[0].val
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'val'

Here is the code...any help will be very much appreciated.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, children, val):
        self.children = children
        self.val = val

Node8 = ([], 8)
Node7 = ([], 7)
Node6 = ([], 6)
Node5 = ([Node6], 5)
Node4 = ([], 4)
Node3 = ([Node7], 3)
Node2 = ([Node4, Node5], 2)
Node1 = Node([Node2, Node3, Node8], 1)


def bfs(r):
    node_list = [r]
    while len(node_list) > 0:
        popped = node_list.pop(0)
        print popped.val
        print "debug"
        print popped.children
        print popped.children[0]
        print popped.children[0].val
        for child in popped.children:
            print child.val
            node_list.append(child)
            print "appended"


bfs(Node1)
```

Comment: You aren't calling the Node constructor for any Node other than `Node1`. You are instead creating 2-tuples, which do not (as the error message states) have a `val` attribute.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Now post that in the answers instead of the comment section.

Comment: @user2357112 Was working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling the `Node` constructor that you created when you create any Node other than `Node1`. You are instead creating 2-tuples, which have no `val` attribute. Add a call to your Node constructor and everything should work fine:

```
# ...
Node8 = Node([], 8)
Node7 = Node([], 7)
Node6 = Node([], 6)
Node5 = Node([Node6], 5)
Node4 = Node([], 4)
Node3 = Node([Node7], 3)
Node2 = Node([Node4, Node5], 2)
Node1 = Node([Node2, Node3, Node8], 1)
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I promptly realized this myself after submitting the question. Sometimes seeing something in a different context makes you realize the obvious!